# Going through an allocated array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Let's say I wanna print the values of an array of type int.

```
int *num = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

How do I do that? I would obviously like to stop after I've gone through all the values I put, which there are 5 of them.

Note that I'm not looking to do something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
```

I want to knwo what happens in the examples I gave.

```
while(*num) {
   printf("%d", *num);
   num++;
}
```

OR

```
while(num != NULL) {
       printf("%d", *num);
       num++;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to store five values or four values? Because if you want to use a sentinel to mark the end of an array, you need to allocate space for the sentinel. Also, you need an "illegal" value to use as the sentinel.

Comment: So you have a problem writing a loop which iterates **`5`** times?

Comment: Strictly speaking you just allocate a piece of memory you treat like an array using a pointer to its first element. `int ` is a pointer, not an array. You have to free this allocated block lateron using **the same** address you got from `malloc`, so you **must not** loose this address! Use another pointer to iterate.

Comment: "I want to knwo what happens in the examples I gave." That makes you question useless and changes its character completely. I feel tempted to rollback, as you are supposed not to change the question once you have answers. I'll leave it at "unclear".

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C don't carry their length. You have to pass the length along with the array.

The easiest way is with a variable:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    printf("%d ", num[i]);
```

The trick with the ending `NUL` is normally used only for strings, the end of the string is marked with a `NUL` char (`'\0'`). Naturally, if you are building and consuming the array yourself, nothing prevents you from making up a similar convention. You can, for instance, mark the end of the array with `-1`:

```
int *num = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
num[4] = -1;
int *p;
for (p = num; *p != -1; ++p)
    printf("%d ", *p);
```

Comment: I know. I'm not looking to do that.

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion: If what you want is to know the length of the array with just the pointer, then there is no such way in standard C.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the allocated array in a way you are showing

```
int *num = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

Then the only way to know the end is to use the size used to allocate the array. Like

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 5)  // 5 here is the size used wile allocating
{
   printf("%d", num[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: .. or even more simple: `num[i]`. Why make it so difficult for a novice?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, True. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the length of the array somewhere. Some other strategies are placing a *terminator* or *sentinel* value at the end of the array (though that value will not be valid for actual content):

```
int *num = calloc(6, sizeof(int));
num[5] = -1;
int i;
for (i = 0; num[i] != -1; i++) {
    //...
}
```

Or embed the length of the array as its first element:

```
int *num = malloc(6 * sizeof(int));
int len = num[0];
int i;
for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

(Note, [Flexible arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) is a better way to express the second example)

Both the above show how to store the length in the array itself, and make use of an extra element for this purpose.

Comment: An array should only contain sematically identical data. Using the first element for the size is a bad idea. Instead a `struct` with _flexible array member_ should be used.

Comment: My point was more to demonstrate how an "array" may physically contain more than just its members, and considering the OP seems fairly new at C, I deemed introducing flexible array members a bit too confusing. Not to mention true flexible array members can either be `[0]` or `[1]` depending on whether C99 or C89 is used...

Comment: FAMs are part of the C standard (too bad C11 made them optional, though). And the semantics are well defined (they have no size and the `struct` does not add 1 element. You might think of proprietary extensions like gcc zero-length arrays or single-element arrays accessing beyond the upper bound, which is actually UB. None of them is a FAM and should not be used anymore (gcc supports FAMs in standard mode).

Comment: Oh, and I think teaching a beginner bad style is the worse of both approaches. But there are alternatives, just use a second variable for the length or a pointer to a VLA, etc.; no need for a `struct` as a FAM requires.

Answer (score -1):

```
while(*num) {
   printf("%d", *num);
   num++;
}
```

Well, this continues until `*num` is zero. This works fine if no valid entry can contain a zero and you have set the last entry (or the first invalid entry) to zero. This is called a sentinel value.

```
while(num != NULL) {
       printf("%d", *num);
       num++;
    }
```

This won't work. Incrementing `num` won't make make it `NULL`. Why would it?

If you have some particular number of values you want to output, you have two basic choices. You can pass the number of values you want to output to the output code and just count as you output that number of values. Or you can use a "sentinel" value to mark the end. If zero is not a valid value you would ever want to print, you can use zero as a sentinel. Don't forget to allocate space for the sentinel.

Comment: Wit this solution you lose the starting address of the memory allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: So something like: for (struct temp* current = array; current != NULL; current++) wouldn't work? (current != NULL is what I'm addressing)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sorry, with what solution?

Comment: with `num++` in your solution as `num` holds the starting address of the allocated memory.

Comment: @SomeoneWithAQuestion Definitely not. Why would incrementing a valid pointer suddenly turn it into the special constant that marks an invalid pointer?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sorry, what solution are you talking about? There isn't even a `malloc` anywhere in my answer.

Comment: David, you posted an "answer" and I call and "answer" a "solution" to the question. And I am refering to the "solution" or "answer" or how you would like to call it, to which I am posting these comments.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I have no idea what you're talking about. These are code snippets and you seem to be assuming someone will connect them together incorrectly and that that's somehow a defect in my answer?!

Comment: No, I mean that the question started with `int *num = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));` and if you now start doing `num++` you lose the starting adress of the memory allocated.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Right. Again, these are code snippets. One shows how `num` gets its value. The others show things you can do with that value. Another thing you can do with that value, not shown, is save it so that you can pass it to `free`. Yes, you can misuse these snippets, but any code can be misused. The snippets are, however, all correct.

Comment: In my opinion your answer must fit with the question, using variables of the question and if using temporary variables is better, then declaring them and using them. A novice programmer may not understand from your snippets that the staring address is lost.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That would just make the concepts I'm trying to explain more difficult to understand. If I was trying to show how to free the allocated memory, you would have a point. But since I'm not, I think you're just asking me to make the answer messier.